# How to find the leading behavior of this integral

Tags: integration, asymptotics, approximation, laplace-method

Consider the integral:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{\pi}\frac{\cos(xt)}{\sqrt{1+a\sin^{2}(x/2)}},\,\,\,\,\,\,\mathrm{as\,\,}t\rightarrow\infty$$

with $a>0.$

I know that the answer is $\exp(-t/\xi)$, where $\xi=1/\ln(2)=1.4427$ for $a=8$

I'm interested in the leading behavior of this integral as $t\rightarrow\infty$ . I tried to applied the Laplace's Method but did not get the answer.

Please help me.

Comment: It goes to zero by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. How fast is told by integration by parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(t)$ be represented by the integral

$$f(t)=\frac1\pi \int_0^\pi \frac{\cos(xt)}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2(x/2)}}\,dx \tag 1$$

Integrating by parts the integral in $(1)$ with $u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2(x/2)}}$ and $v=\frac{\sin(xt)}{t}$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
f(t)&= \frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi \sqrt{2}\,t}+\frac1{4\pi t} \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(xt)\sin(x)}{\left(1+\sin^2(x/2)\right)^{3/2}}\,dx \tag 2\\\\
&=\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi \sqrt{2}\,t}+o\left(\frac1{t^2}\right) \tag3
\end{align}$$

Note that integrating by parts the integral in $(2)$ with $u=\frac{\sin(x)}{\left(1+\sin^2(x/2)\right)^{3/2}}$ and $v=-\frac{\cos(xt)}{t}$ would produce a term that is of order $o\left(\frac{1}{t^2}\right)$, thereby producing $(3)$.

Comment: This is correct, but I am looking for an exponentially decaying factor of the type  $\exp(-t/\xi)$, where $\xi$ is some numerical factor. Do you have any idea. Thanks, and thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't decay exponentially, as shown by the posted development.  Rather, the leading term is of order $1/t$.

Comment: Dr. MV, I will present the original problem. In the paper [link](http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.55.8894),  the previous integral appears, and they obtain   "For $n\rightarrow\infty$, we can show that the leading behavior of this is given by an exponentially decaying factor $\exp(-n/\xi)$ , where $\xi^{-1}=\ln(s_{1}/s_{2})$. For $s_{1}=1$, $s_{2}=1/2$, we get $\xi=1.44$"

Comment: I had access to the abstract only, so cannot read the passage you quoted.  Why do you believe that the integral in the OP could possibly decay exponentially when we've established that the leading term decays as $1/t$?

Comment: Here is the paper. https://www.dropbox.com/s/wod46nrm2sc2f90/Physical%20Review%20B%20Volume%2055%20issue%2014%201997.pdf?dl=0. The authors were looking for the spin correlations behavior, and it is convenient to express this as  an exponential decaying factor. See Eq. (11) and Eq. (7) of the mentioned paper.

Comment: The authors never defined $J$ as far as I was able to see.  What is $J$?  What is $s_1+s_2$ and why is this inside the integral if they are independent of $k$?

Comment: Substituting Eq.(7) into Eq.(11), $J$ is cancelled, therefore, $J$ play no role in the integral. The $s_{1}$ and $s_{2}$ terms are the spin, i.e., in the case of interest they are only numerical factors.

Comment: Well, I don't see the rationale for carrying the spin numbers inside the integral if they are independent of $k$.  So, that might be an issue.  Also, what is $J$?  If it is an operator, then that poses another possible issue.  In any case, the integral in the OP decays with leading term $O(1/t)$ and does not decay exponentially.

Answer (score 4):

For $t \to \infty$ over the reals, the integral is $\sin(\pi t)/(\pi t \sqrt {a + 1}) + o(t^{-2})$.

But I assume that you're looking for the asymptotic of the Fourier series coefficients of $f(x) = (1 + a \sin^2(x/2))^{-1/2}$, that is, $t \to \infty$ over the integers.

In that case, if we take a contour going in the direction $i$ from the points $\pm\pi$ and avoiding the branch cut of $f$ lying on the imaginary axis, the main contribution to the integral of $f(x) e^{i t x}$ comes not from the endpoints but from the part of the contour going along the branch cut, because the integrals over $[-\pi, -\pi + i \infty)$ and $(\pi + i \infty, \pi]$ cancel out.

The branch point at $x_0 = 2 i \operatorname{arcsinh}(1 / \sqrt a)$ is of the $x^{-1/2}$ type, and the integral of $f(x) e^{i t x}$ from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ is twice the integral from $x_0$ to $i \infty$, for which Laplace's method gives
$$f(x) = (a+1)^{-1/4} (i(x-x_0))^{-1/2} + O(|x-x_0|^{1/2})
 \quad \text{when } x \to x_0,\\
\frac 1 {2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) \cos t x \,dx =
\frac 1 \pi \int_{x_0}^{i \infty} f(x) e^{i t x} \,dx \sim \\
\frac 1 \pi (a+1)^{-1/4}
 \int_{x_0}^{i \infty} (i(x - x_0))^{-1/2} \,e^{i t x} dx = \\
\frac i \pi (a+1)^{-1/4} e^{i x_0 t}
 \int_0^\infty (-x)^{-1/2} \,e^{-t x} dx = \\
(a+1)^{-1/4} (\pi t)^{-1/2}
 \exp \left( -2 t \operatorname{arcsinh} \frac 1 {\sqrt a} \right).$$