# Trend of a definite integral as a function of the domain size

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, power-series

I would like to study the integral $I(L)$ (where $L$ is a positive integer):
$$
I(L)= \int\limits_{{-}\pi L}^{{+}\pi L}
 \sqrt[4]{1-\cos\Big(\frac{q}{L}\Big)} \cos(q) dq
$$
in the limit $L\to\infty$.

EDIT:
From a numerical experiment in Wolfram alpha I expect this integral to go to zero as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}$:

```
integrate_{-5*\pi}^{5*\pi}\sqrt[4]{1-cos(x/5)}*cos(x)dx = -0.47
integrate_{-50*\pi}^{50*\pi}\sqrt[4]{1-cos(x/50)}*cos(x)dx = -0.149
integrate_{-500*\pi}^{500*\pi}\sqrt[4]{1-cos(x/500)}*cos(x)dx = -0.047
integrate_{-1000*\pi}^{1000*\pi}\sqrt[4]{1-cos(x/1000)}*cos(x)dx = -0.033
```

I would like to prove analytically the result above, i.e. I would like to understand the origin of the trend  $I(L)\sim_{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}$.

To this aim, I tried to expand the cosine and collect the first power
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lim_{L\to\infty}I(L)&= \lim_{L\to\infty}\int\limits_{{-}\pi L}^{{+}\pi L}
 \sqrt[4]{1-\cos\Big(\frac{q}{L}\Big)} \cos(q) dq\\
 &=\lim_{L\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\int\limits_{{-}\pi L}^{{+}\pi L}
 \sqrt[4]{({q})^2 \sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{n}}{(2[n+1])!}} \Big(\frac{q}{L}\Big)^{2n}} \cos(q) dq=\\
 &=\lim_{L\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\int\limits_{{-}\pi L}^{{+}\pi L}
 \sqrt[4]{({q})^2 \Big(\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}\Big(\frac{q}{L}\Big)^{2}+\frac{1}{4!}\Big(\frac{q}{L}\Big)^{4}+\dots} \cos(q) dq
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$
Now I was hoping to be able to show that
$$
\lim_{L\to\infty}
  \left|\int_{-\pi L}^{+\pi L}
 \sqrt[4]{q^2 \left(\frac{1}{2!}
                 - \frac{1}{3!} \left(\frac{q}{L}\right)^2
                 + \frac{1}{4!} \left(\frac{q}{L}\right)^4+\dots\right)}
\cos(q) dq\right|
\sim C\hspace{5mm} (*)
$$
where $C$ is a positive constant. But this does not seem straightforward to me.

Does anyone see if there is any simple way to prove equation $(*)$?
I expect $(*)$ to be true due to the numerical evidence listed above.

Comment: Soft evidence that this is the correct rate - 
$$ I(L) = \int_{-\pi}^\pi (1-\cos(q))^{1/4} \cos(Lq) \ dq$$
i.e. $I(L)$ is the $L$th Fourier coefficient of $f(q)=(1-\cos(q))^{1/4}$. As $1-\cos q$ is like $Cq^2$, $f\in C^{1/2}$. Thus $|I(L)| \le \frac C{\sqrt L}$ by Zygmund's theorem (e.g. theorem 1.8 in https://www-m7.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/M7/Analysis/Fourier13/lecture9.pdf )

Comment: Would accept this as an answer. Could you please tell me the reference [Zy] cited in the notes?

Comment: Hmm, are you sure? this only provides an upper bound, and may not be 'sharp', i.e. it may be possible that $I(L) \le \frac{1}{L^{100}}$ somehow... I know of some resources but I dont know how good they are as introductory books. You can try Folland's Real Analysis and (much harder) Grafakos Classical Fourier Analysis and also a second book Modern Fourier Analysis? Stein, E. & Shakarchi, R. Fourier Analysis, an Introduction seems to be reasonably popular

[Zy] is presumably Zygmund's two volume Trigonometric Series, but I'm not sure

Comment: (actually, your $I(L)$ is not the fourier coefficient, the fourier coefficient has an additional factor of $1/L$, but without this factor $I(L)$ wouldn't converge to 0 anyway so I guess this factor should have been there)

Comment: Indeed I started from $A(L)=\int\limits_{-\pi}^{+\pi}\sqrt[4]{1-\cos(q')} e^{+iq'L} dq '$ then performed the substitution $q'L=q$ obtaining $A=\frac{1}{L} I(L)$. Here I reported only $I(L)$ with the aim to simplify the discussion.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I have edited the text inserting the results of the numerical test that should show the convergence to zero of the integral

Comment: Oh. Well that's interesting, because the above theorem only gives you that $|I(L)/L| \le L^{-1/2}$, i.e. $|I(L)| \le \sqrt L$, which I expected to be a nearly optimal result...

Comment: I have some counter numerical evidence, please see this graph

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/l6ew1ce0i5

it indicates that the should be a pretty big hump in between regions approximately like $[n,n+1]$, and if you check further out there's

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=compute+integral+from+-pi+to+pi+of+(1-cos(x))%5E(1%2F4)+1000.5+cos(1000.5+x)+dx

which is like 2.3. I don't know what happens for integer valued $L$....

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, indeed I have forgotten to specify that $L$ must be integer. I have edited the text

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where the asymptotic of the Fourier coefficients of $f(u) = (1 - \cos u)^{1/4}$ is determined by the branch point of $f$ which is nearest to the real line. The integrals over the rays $[-\pi, -\pi + i \infty)$ and $[\pi, \pi + i \infty)$ are the same, thus $I(L)$ is equal to the integral along the banks of the branch cut $[0, i \infty)$. That integral can be estimated by applying Laplace's method. In the same way as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2838782), we obtain
$$f(i \xi \pm 0) \sim
\frac {1 \pm i} {2^{3/4}} \sqrt \xi \quad\text{when } \xi \to 0^+, \\
I(L) = L \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(u) e^{i L u} du \sim
i L \int_0^\infty \frac {2 i} {2^{3/4}} \sqrt \xi \,e^{-L \xi} d\xi = \\
-\sqrt {\frac \pi {2^{3/2} L}},
\quad L \to \infty, \;L \in \mathbb N.$$